# i18n of Flex Alert.show(..) buttons

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, internationalization

I have to change the "Yes" and "No" buttons in an Alert.show(..), to another language (Dutch, for instance).
Is there a (easy) way to do that?

I forgot to mention - I have a -locale nl_NL in my compiler options, but it is still Yes/No

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this example](http://flexexamples.blogspot.com/2008/01/styling-flex-alert-control.html) you can use `Alert.yesLabel = "Accept";` and `Alert.noLabel = "Reject";` to customize text in the yes and no buttons with your own string.
Look at [this docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Alert.html) to set the tile.